# QT - How can I get characters from QString?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a couple of strings which are storing "RNA,DNA" sequences. I need to get characters from these strings and compare them.

Below you can see a part of my code:

```
QFile file (filePath);
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
    QMessageBox::information(0,"info",file.errorString());
}

QString line, element;
QStringList list;
int counter;

while(!file.atEnd()){
    line = file.readLine();
    list = line.split(QRegExp("[\r\n]"),QString::SkipEmptyParts);
    for(counter = 0; counter < list.size();  counter++){
        element=list.at(counter);
        textfile_.append(element);
    }
}
```

Now, what I want to do is, slice the "element" variable character by character and store these characters in to the variables, strings, vectors or whatever. But I have to reach them later to be able to compare them.

> Simple sample:
>
> - element1: "actrcddeactsfgcstrsac"
> - element2: "actcctdfascrtasc"
> - element3: "sdfccwertwerwewerdf"
> - element4: "werwercdwttewrweddfer"
>
> lets say for the element1 what I need is something like that:
>
> - char[0][0]=a
> - char[0][1]=c
> - char[0][2]=t
> - ...

Comment: What about `QString::at()` function that returns `QChar` by the character index?

Comment: Can you please explain more. I am not that good on qt. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that. Below are some of them:

**Method 1** - use list of strings

```
QString element1("actrcddeactsfgcstrsac");
QList<QString> matrix;
matrix.push_back(element1);
char c = matrix[0][0].toAscii(); // returns 'a'
```

**Method 2** - using a two dimensional array. I would take std::vector to store the characters:

```
QString element1("actrcddeactsfgcstrsac");
// Init the 100x100 matrix
std::vector<std::vector<char> > matrix( 100, std::vector<char>(100, 0));

// Init the first row.
for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
    matrix[0][i] = element1.at(i).toAscii();
}

char c = matrix[0][0]; // returns 'a'
```

Comment: @ArdaÖzceviz, you probably use Qt 5.x, where `QChar::fromAscii()` function is obsolete. You can use `QChar::toLatin1()` instead.